# Python. What happens if we take list() function from the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a code:

```
keys = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
value = [1]
vowels = { key : list(value) for key in keys }
print(vowels)
value.append(2)
print(vowels)
```

The result of this code:

```
{'a':[1],'e':[1],'i':[1],'o':[1],'u':[1]}
{'a':[1],'e':[1],'i':[1],'o':[1],'u':[1]}
```

---

The following code:

```
keys = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
value = [1]
vowels = { key : value for key in keys }
print(vowels)
value.append(2)
print(vowels)
```

gives me another result:

```
{'a':[1],'e':[1],'i':[1],'o':[1],'u':[1]}
{'a':[1,2],'e':[1,2],'i':[1,2],'o':[1,2],'u':[1,2]}
```

Why it happens if `value` and `list(value)` are both give the same list object?

Comment: You invert the output with their corresponding output

Comment: why not simply try it in the interactive console ?

Comment: Same list object vs. new list object constructed from existing list’s values…

Comment: [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#func-list) accepts iterable - so it's constructing always a new list object. With only `value` you're referencing the same object.

Answer (score 0):

The code `list(value)` create a **new** list with the content of `value`, so if you modify `value` after, that has no effect.

```
value = [1] ---> a list instance
{
 'u': [1], ----> a list instance copied from value
 'a': [1], ----> a list instance copied from value
 'e': [1], ----> a list instance copied from value
 'i': [1], ----> a list instance copied from value
 'o': [1]  ----> a list instance copied from value
 }
```

But in `vowels = {key: value for key in keys}` you set the unique instance of the list `value` as the value of each key, all refers to the unique list `[1]` so of you modify it, you can see it in the dict as **that** list is being used

```
value = [1,2] ---> a list instance
{                  ^
 'u': [1, 2], -----|    refers to value object
 'a': [1, 2], -----|    refers to value object
 'e': [1, 2], -----|    refers to value object
 'i': [1, 2], -----|    refers to value object
 'o': [1, 2]  -----|    refers to value object
}
```